# How to get object from binding source

Tags: wpf, object, data-binding

In WPF, I have a listbox binding to a Dataset which looks like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_Configuration" SelectionMode="Extended" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
```

The SelectedItem has many objects like: *id*, *name*, *value*...

How could I get this value in the back end code? my thought is：

```
int myid;
myid = lb_Configuration.SelectedItem.<what method?>
```

Or someother way to achieve my purpose？Thanks.

Comment: What is _back end code_? Do you mean the code-behind of your UI? That would be a wrong way, you have to manage your data in the view-model, not in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do mean code-behind. But `myid` is not a UI view object, I just want to get it's value for calculating process

Comment: If you wrote a Binding for the `SelectedItem` property to the `SelectedProduct` property, the natural question is: where is the `SelectedProduct` property? In the xaml.cs? In the ViewModel?

Comment: In the ViewModel

Comment: if you are selecting multiple values its 'SelectedItems' you are looking for not 'SelectedItem' if you aren't then no point in the `SelectionMode="Extended"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the `SelectedItem` property to your type (`Product` or whatever your class is called) using the `as` operator:

```
int myid;
var item = lb_Configuration.SelectedItem as Product;
if(item != null)
    myid = item.Id;
```

Note that, since you bind the `SelectedItem` property to a `SelectedProduct` property in your view model, you could access the `Id` property of the `SelectedProduct` directly in the view model class though:

```
int myid;
if(SelectedProduct != null)
    myid = SelectedProduct.Id;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to access it in back end code, you can do

```
myID = (lb_Configuration.SelectedItem as (Type of the object it is binded to)).ID;
```

But it's good to avoid xaml.cs code behind. If you explain what you actually want to achieve, I can help you with the MVVM way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have wrote a `SelectedProduct` to get the product from a *xml* file, and each `Product` has many objects in the *xml* file like: *id*, *name*, *value*, Now when i click a button, i need to get one of the object from the `Product` i already choosed in my listbox. Hope i explained this clearly to you.

Comment: _"it's good to avoid xaml.cs code behind"_ no it's not. It depends on what you have to achieve and what's your programming style. The best practice wants that you put all the logic in your ViewModels class and leave in the View only the UI stuffs, but apart from that, you can handle the View in whatever way you want.

Comment: I wrote the view-model like this: `public Product SelectedProduct
        {
            get { return selectedProduct; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedProduct != value)
                {
                    selectedProduct = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }`